# What is the meaning of "|-" in coq, and how do I find the definitions for the other seemingly undocumented notations?

Tags: coq

What does the "|-" mean in coq? It seems to be used where one might reference a term or pattern for example:

```
 simpl in |- *.
```

or, from Coq.Init.Tauto,

```
Local Ltac not_dep_intros :=
  repeat match goal with
  | |- (forall (_: ?X1), ?X2) => intro
  | |- (Coq.Init.Logic.not _) => unfold Coq.Init.Logic.not at 1; intro
  end.
```

But the coq reference manual only says it's loaded in the prelude and may be over written. While the standard library documentation says nothing. On top of that commands like Search, Locate, Check, Print, Unfold, etc. don't seem to be able to give any information on that either.

"[=" and "**" are even more mysterious as I only know the exist because the manual says they are loaded in the prelude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|-` token is documented [in the reference manual under `goal_occurences`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#grammar-token-goal_occurrences).  The meaning is generally to separate the hypotheses from the goals, as `|-` is the ASCII rendition of `⊢` which is used in mathematics for the same purpose.  So `simpl in * |-` means "`simpl` in the hypotheses" and `simpl in |- *` means "`simpl` in the goal" while `simpl in H |- *` means "`simpl` in `H` and also the goal".  Unfortunately the syntax is not documented for `simpl` (I've reported this as a bug [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/13803)), but it is documented [here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/rewriting.html#coq:tacn.rewrite) for `rewrite`.

The syntax for `|-` in `match goal` is documented [here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.match-goal), and serves the same purpose of dividing hypothesis patterns from goal patterns.

Generally, the best place to locate tactics is in [the tactic index in the reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/coq-tacindex.html), but I think these are not proper tactics that you are talking about.  I think you are thinking of `intros **` and `intros [= H]`, which are both intro patterns.  See [this documentation of `intros`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.intros-%E2%80%A6).  In particular [the grammar for `intropattern_list`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#grammar-token-intropattern_list) says:

> - `[= intropattern*, ]` — If the product is over an equality type, applies either `injection` or `discriminate`. If injection is applicable, the `intropattern` is used on the hypotheses generated by `injection`. If the number of patterns is smaller than the number of hypotheses generated, the pattern `?` is used to complete the list. Example
> - `**` — introduces one or more quantified variables or hypotheses from the result until there are no more quantified variables or implications (`->`). `intros **` is equivalent to `intros`. Example

Answer (score 0):

To find the definitions for the other seemingly undocumented notations?

Try this general index: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/genindex.html